# Laravel insert escaped string in blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an app where admin can store analytics code to database. I save this code with:

```
$analytics = htmlentities($value);
```

So I end up with something like this in my DB:

```
&lt;script&gt;
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
 (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('send', 'pageview');

&lt;/script&gt;
```

Then I try to output this in my blade template:

```
{!! $site_settings->get("analyticsCode")->value !!}
```

Unfortunately blade cannot unescape the script section:

```
&lt;script&gt;
```

I have tried also with HTML::decode without success.

Comment: So the `<` and `>` are saved as `&lt;` and `&gt;` in the database row? Did you try a simple `str_replace` to output them as `<` and `>`?

Comment: Of course, this could be a solution. But I'm searching a different solution, if it's possible, to make this work in an laravel way. I could of course store only the js code without the script tag, but I would like to know if this is a security problem or there is a way to output like in my example.

Comment: Did you try `HTML::decode()` ? It's a wrapper for `html_entity_decode()`

Comment: Yes I've tried but with wrong syntax. This seems to work: `{!! Html::decode( $site_settings->get("analyticsCode")->value ) !!}` The double exclamation mark do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HTML::decode()` which is a wrapper for the php `html_entity_decode()` function.

Laravel 5:

```
{!! Html::decode( $site_settings->get("analyticsCode")->value ) !!}
```

Laravel 4:

```
{{ Html::decode( $site_settings->get("analyticsCode")->value ) }}
```